# Does PostgreSQL have any guards for alias names?

Tags: postgresql

Sometimes when I'm running queries on the fly, I'll forget a comma between field names.  Postgres won't catch my mistake because the query is still valid as far as it's concerned;  It just treats one field as an alias for the other.

If I'm retrieving the results directly from a dba tool like PgAdmin, it's immediately obvious what has happened and I'll insert a comma.  However, if I'm saving the results of a query directly to a file, I don't usually find the mistake until later when I'm trying to use that file.

Does PostgreSQL have any functionality to check for this type of scenario or to force the use of "AS" when declaring column aliases?  This is a minor nuisance that can be hard to catch right away.

Comment: That feature is pretty much [hard-baked into the SQL parser](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c55de5e5123ce58ee19a47c08425949599285041/src/backend/parser/gram.y#L14634), so unfortunately: no.

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is to qualify your output columns with the table name; `SELECT t.x t.y` throws a syntax error due to the `.` in the alias